# How can I individually expand the 3 collapsible cards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Mui5. I have a similar recurring card and once I click the expand button, all other cards expand. How can I only expand those that needs to be expanded once clicking on the specific button of the card?

I recreated a code sandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cerf-pelzk7?file=/demo.js

Below are the sample codes

```
export default function RecipeReviewCard() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            1st sample
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </ExpandMore>
        </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>

            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet
              over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook,
              stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes.
              Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
              and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic,
              tomatoes, onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring often until
              thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add saffron broth and
              remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>

      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            2nd Sample
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </ExpandMore>
        </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>

            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet
              over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook,
              stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes.
              Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
              and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic,
              tomatoes, onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring often until
              thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add saffron broth and
              remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>

      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            3rd Sample
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <FavoriteIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            onClick={handleExpandClick}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </ExpandMore>
        </CardActions>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron
              and set aside for 10 minutes.
            </Typography>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet
              over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook,
              stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes.
              Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
              and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic,
              tomatoes, onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring often until
              thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add saffron broth and
              remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Collapse>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Since put JS as your tag, you can `for` loop them, and if the event is pressed, open only that one.

Answer (score 0):

In you ExpandMore components, you are using the same state for all three of them.

Try to create three different state or create a array to store such states, so you can control them separately

```
//You are using one state for three ExpandMore Component.
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

<ExpandMore
   expand={expanded} //this state
   onClick={handleExpandClick}
   aria-expanded={expanded}
   aria-label="show more"
>
```